# Inconsistent Favicon Display: Filename Impact in EJS Files

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, favicon

Why is it that when I change the filename of the favicon from "favicon.png" to a random name like "icon.png" or "img.png" it resolves the issue and the favicon displays correctly on the website(favicon part) when linked in an EJS file? I'm curious to know if this is a widespread occurrence or if it's an isolated incident, as I've noticed that using the "favicon.png" filename doesn't display the favicon on the website and by simply renaming the favicon file and keeping the same file path, the favicon starts displaying correctly on the website.

During my server-side project, I encountered an issue where the favicon wasn't displaying on the website's favicon section after hastily renaming it as "favicon.png." However, when I changed the filename to "icon.png," it started appearing correctly. just wanted to know more about this issue